# React-Redux action dispatch Issue?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

This is the Code down below, I am unable to call userLoginRequest. userLoginRequest simply authenticate Users, I am unable to dispatch acion for userLoginRequest. I am newbie to react and react-redux so please guide me.

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Helmet from 'react-helmet';
import { createStructuredSelector } from 'reselect';
import makeSelectLoginContainer from './selectors';
import Login from 'components/Login';
import { userLoginRequest } from './actions';


export class LoginContainer extends React.PureComponent { // eslint-disable-line react/prefer-stateless-function
  doLogin(username, password) {
    console.log('DoLogin', username, password);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Login handleSubmit={this.doLogin}></Login>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

LoginContainer.propTypes = {
  userLoginRequest: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  LoginContainer: makeSelectLoginContainer(),
});


function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    userLoginRequest: (username, password) => dispatch(actions.userLoginRequest(username, password)),
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginContainer);
```

Comment: I see you call out wrong login request function `handleSubmit={this.props.userLoginRequest}`, make sure the Login component passes the username, password as parameter

Answer (score 0):

You have already destructured you actions module

```
userLoginRequest: (username, password) => dispatch(userLoginRequest(username, password)),
```

or do not destruct actions

```
import * as actions from './actions';
```

And surely you need to call `this.props.userLoginRequest` inside `doLogin` method :)

Comment: thank you. that solved my problem. Can you suggest me some websites to clear my fundamentals about react and redux

Comment: No problem. Redux' docs are actually good http://redux.js.org/ But this problem was more about es**Whaterever** fundamentals.